# program to handle Heterogeneous Lists in Scala;

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have to find out the maximum/minimum from this list:

```
 val data= List(List(1,2), List(3,4,91,9,10),11,211,456,345)
```

From some stack over flow example ,i can see below solution:

```
val flatdata=data.collect{case i:Int => List(i); case l @ a :: b => l}.flatten
```

[
But this is giving error]

Can some one please help.
want the solution using pure scala and not spark

Answer (score 2):

Let's go through your code in more detail:

```
sacla> val data= List(List(1,2), List(3,4,91,9,10),11,211,456,345)
data: List[Any] = List(List(1, 2), List(3, 4, 91, 9, 10), 11, 211, 456, 345)
```

The type of data is a `List[Any]` because the list is not one specific type. The compiler tries to infer the type, but since `Int` and `List[Int]` aren't compatible, it resolves to `Any`.

```
scala> data.collect{case i:Int => List(i); case l @ a :: b => l}
res0 List[List[Any]] = List(List(1, 2), List(3, 4, 91, 9, 10), List(11), List(211), List(456), List(345))
```

This second part, tries to consolidate the entries to be a List of Lists. It matches an `Int` and wraps it in a `List`.

However, you see the type here is still `List[List[Any]]`.

Now the last part, the `.flatten`

```
scala> res0.flatten
res1: List[Any] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 91, 9, 10, 11, 211, 456, 345)
```

This takes you from a `List[List[Any]` to `List[Any]`.

Now the key part here is that if you try to call `.max` or `.min` on this list, it won't work. Since there is no such `Ordering` for `Any`.

```
<console>:13: error: No implicit Ordering defined for Any.
```

The fix will be to force the this type in the original `collect` call.

```
scala> data.collect{case i:Int => List(i); case l : List[Int] => l}
res6: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2), List(3, 4, 91, 9, 10), List(11), List(211), List(456), List(345))


scala> .flatten
res7: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 91, 9, 10, 11, 211, 456, 345)

scala> .max
res8: Int = 456

scala> res7.min
res9: Int = 1
```

Comment: Thank u so much ELinda:-)

Answer (score 1):

One thing wrong with your code is that the result is `List[Any]`, which isn't going to be terribly useful.

This gives a compiler warning but produces a `List[Int]` result.

```
data.flatMap{case li:List[Int] => li; case i:Int => List(i)}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your code, it evaluates fine. Not sure what error you're getting.

```scala
scala>  val data= List(List(1,2), List(3,4,91,9,10),11,211,456,345)
data: List[Any] = List(List(1, 2), List(3, 4, 91, 9, 10), 11, 211, 456, 345)

scala> data.collect{case i:Int => List(i); case l @ a :: b => l}
res0: List[List[Any]] = List(List(1, 2), List(3, 4, 91, 9, 10), List(11), List(211), List(456), List(345))

scala> data.collect{case i:Int => List(i); case l @ a :: b => l}.flatten
res1: List[Any] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 91, 9, 10, 11, 211, 456, 345)
```

Comment: val data1= List(List(1,2), List(3,4,91,9,10),11,211,456,345)
  val flatdata=data1.collect{case i:Int => List(i); case l @ a :: b => l}
  println(flatdata.max)
  println(flatdata.min)   getting below error:Error:(24, 20) not enough arguments for method min: (implicit cmp: Ordering[List[Any]])List[Any].
Unspecified value parameter cmp.
  println(flatdata.min)

Comment: i am trying to run via intellijee

Comment: @tulirishi please see my answer. It goes into detail as to why you are seeing this error, and how to solve it.